# R: reshape elements of a data frame keeping order of variables in sequence

Tags: r, list, dataframe, reshape

I'm struggling with reshaping 12 separate list elements [which are in data frame format] and having the values stay in the right sequential order. These are measurements by day, with `value 1` corresponding to the first day of the month measurement, and so on until `value 31`, the maximum possible days/month. This is in a horizontal. For missing measurements/months where there are fewer than 31 days, `-9999` appears. The `-9999` is not the problem here.

```
> myplist[[1]]
     COOPID YEAR MONTH ELEMENT value 1 value 2 value 3 value 4 value 5 value 6 
3    170100 1982     9    PRCP       0      70      15       0       0       0       
8    170100 1982    10    PRCP       0      10       0       0       0       0       
13   170100 1982    11    PRCP       2      13       0     170       0       5       
18   170100 1982    12    PRCP       0       0       0       0       2       5       
23   170100 1983     1    PRCP       2       0       0       0       0      10       
28   170100 1983     2    PRCP   -9999       0       0      52       6       0
```

My goal is to have the list elements oriented vertically so that each day has its own row, so it would look like this:

```
> myplist[[1]]
    YEAR MONTH DAY PRCP
    1982     9   1    0
    1982     9   2   70
    1982     9   3   15
```

I tried this code:

```
melt(myplist[[1]], id.vars = c("COOPID", "YEAR", "MONTH", "ELEMENT"))
```

But it listed the `value 1` of each month rather than the desired sequence of `value 1`, `value 2`, ..., `value 31`.

```
      COOPID YEAR MONTH ELEMENT variable value
1     170100 1982     9    PRCP  value 1     0
2     170100 1982    10    PRCP  value 1     0
3     170100 1982    11    PRCP  value 1     2
4     170100 1982    12    PRCP  value 1     0
5     170100 1983     1    PRCP  value 1     2
```

And this code returned this undesired output and error:

```
> reshape(myplist[[1]], idvar = c("YEAR","MONTH"),varying =print(paste0("value",1:31)),sep = "",
+         timevar = c("YEAR","MONTH"),direction = "long")
 [1] "value1"  "value2"  "value3"  "value4"  "value5"  "value6"  "value7"  "value8"  "value9"  "value10"
[11] "value11" "value12" "value13" "value14" "value15" "value16" "value17" "value18" "value19" "value20"
[21] "value21" "value22" "value23" "value24" "value25" "value26" "value27" "value28" "value29" "value30"
[31] "value31"
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , varying.i) : undefined columns selected
```

I also tried dcast to no avail, and other asked questions on the this and other sites don't seem to get at the issue I'm having. I think the root of the problem is that my range of years has variable length days per month (goes to the actual last day of a given month), but each month in my measurement data has 31 day values regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a *tidy* approach, I would `gather` the value columns into long format and then `gsub` to be day of the month.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(text = "
     COOPID YEAR MONTH ELEMENT 'value 1' 'value 2' 'value 3' 'value 4' 'value 5' 'value 6'
     170100 1982     9    PRCP         0        70        15         0         0         0
     170100 1982    10    PRCP         0        10         0         0         0         0
     170100 1982    11    PRCP         2        13         0       170         0         5
     170100 1982    12    PRCP         0         0         0         0         2         5
     170100 1983     1    PRCP         2         0         0         0         0        10
     170100 1983     2    PRCP     -9999         0         0        52         6         0
                 ", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% as_tibble

df %>%
  select(-ELEMENT) %>%
  gather(DAY, PRCP, -c(COOPID, YEAR, MONTH)) %>%
  mutate(DAY = as.integer(gsub("value\\.", "", DAY))) %>%
  arrange(COOPID, YEAR, MONTH, DAY)

# # A tibble: 36 x 5
#    COOPID  YEAR MONTH   DAY  PRCP
#     <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#  1 170100  1982     9     1     0
#  2 170100  1982     9     2    70
#  3 170100  1982     9     3    15
#  4 170100  1982     9     4     0
#  5 170100  1982     9     5     0
#  6 170100  1982     9     6     0
#  7 170100  1982    10     1     0
#  8 170100  1982    10     2    10
#  9 170100  1982    10     3     0
# 10 170100  1982    10     4     0
# # ... with 26 more rows
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! It should be noted for other users that I did have to alter the mutate function to "value" instead of "value\\." because of the way tibbles format headers it initially made the DAY column fill with NAs.

Comment: @adgelov, yes, it is not shown explicitly in my code. However, `read.table` is producing a standard data frame that retains the column names provided and I have added `as_tibble` to that pipe. Those column names would not have been considered *valid* if created initially as a tibble.